# Pooled autocorrelation and AR model coefficients in a multivariate time series

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, pooling

I'm reading a paper where the authors generate AR(p) data for use in a sensitivity analysis. They get the coefs for the model by estimating the "pooled AR coefficients from the multivariate time series." I know from earlier in the paper that the multivariate time series goes something like this in `R`:

```
A <- c(0.6,0.2,-0.1)
n <- 512
m <- 8
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*m),ncol = m, nrow = n)
for(i in 1:m){
  x[,i] <- arima.sim(model = list(order=c(3,0,0), ar = A), n = n) 
}
```

The paper says they "estimate the pooled autocorrelation and AR model coefficients." I'm not sure what they mean by that. How does one pool AR coefficients across the columns of `x`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the fitted separate AR models of the same order (e.g., AR(1)) to each series and then 'pooled' (i.e., averaged) the resulting estimated autoregressive coeffcients (e.g., averaged the AR(1) coefficients)? You might need to email the authors to clarify that - only they know what they actually did!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well, they make it clear that this the pooling is a multivariate process and not a mean of the individual models. I'm not familiar with the concept of pooling really. I have to do some more reading.